# Highcharts need parse data for showing points?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, highcharts

I have highcharts:

```
            data: (function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/flkLive/ws/root/success",
                    success: function(values){

                        getAllDataValues(values);
                    }
                });
            }())
        }]
    });
```

});

function getAllDataValues(values) {

```
var array_keys = [];
var array_values = [];
var data = [];

for (var key in values) {
    if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        array_keys.push(key);
        array_values.push(values[key]);
    }
}
array_keys.sort();
array_values.sort();

for (var i = 0; i < array_keys.length; i++){
    data.push(Date.parse(array_keys[i] + " UTC"), parseFloat(array_values[i]))
}

alert(data);
return data;
```

}

But no values appear in the chart...

The alert show the values correctly!

Thanks!

Comment: Take some time and format your question correctly and we will help.

Comment: to see the format of your data you can use console.log instead of alert. Have you considered using $.getJSON instead of standard Ajax call? Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: "The alert show the values correctly!" - show us the values

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/flkLive/ws/root/success', function(data) {
      $('#container').highcharts({
        series: [{
          data: getAllDataValues(data)
        }]
      });
    });
  });

  function getAllDataValues(values) {

    var array_keys = [];
    var array_values = [];
    var data = [];

    for (var key in values) {
      if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        array_keys.push(key);
        array_values.push(values[key]);
      }
    }
    array_keys.sort();
    array_values.sort();

    for (var i = 0; i < array_keys.length; i++) {
      data.push(Date.parse(array_keys[i] + " UTC"), parseFloat(array_values[i]))
    }

    alert(data);
    return data;
  }
});
```

Comment: work but using return [
        [Date.parse("2016-09-20 21:25 UTC"), 66]
    ];

Comment: What is not working? I haven't done any changes to your `getAllDataValues()`. How is the data from the service structured?